# serialize object with XmlDocument Property

Tags: c#, serialization, xmldocument, session-state-server, state-server

I have  to many classes that contains  some field and properties of type `XmlDocument`.
When I put the objects of these classes in session (such as state Server, SQL State Server) it is necessary to serialize them.
But if we have a property of type XmlDocument and add  `[Serialize]` Attribute above our class, the following error will be appears .

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

this error does not appears for the fields have `[NonSerialize]` attribute. the properties can’t have  the attribute `[NonSerialize]` because it can be used only for class and struct and  event and delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, according to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx), the state server uses [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to serialize complex types.  `BinaryFormatter` serializes all public and private *fields* (not properties!) of a class or struct that is marked as [`[Serializable]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  But [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as you have noted, is not so marked, thus cannot be immediately serialized with `BinaryFormatter`.

`XmlDocument` can, however, be trivially converted from and to a string -- the XML itself that the document represents.  Thus if the `XmlDocument` field were contained in a type implementing [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then its [`GetObjectData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.getobjectdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could simply store the corresponding XML string inside the serialization stream.  Then the corresponding serialization constructor could extract the XML string and reconstitute the `XmlDocument`.

Since implementing `ISerializable` on a pre-existing class can be time consuming, the easiest way to accomplish what you want would be to introduce a small serialization wrapper struct for your XML documents:

```
[Serializable]
public struct XmlDocumentSerializationWrapper : ISerializable
{
    public static implicit operator XmlDocumentSerializationWrapper(XmlDocument data) { return new XmlDocumentSerializationWrapper(data); }

    public static implicit operator XmlDocument(XmlDocumentSerializationWrapper wrapper) { return wrapper.XmlDocument; }

    private readonly XmlDocument xmlDocument;

    public XmlDocument XmlDocument { get { return xmlDocument; } }

    public XmlDocumentSerializationWrapper(XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        this.xmlDocument = xmlDocument;
    }

    public XmlDocumentSerializationWrapper(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var xml = (string)info.GetValue("XmlDocument", typeof(string));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
        {
            xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
        }
        else
        {
            xmlDocument = null;
        }
    }

    #region ISerializable Members

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (XmlDocument != null)
        {
            var xml = XmlDocument.OuterXml;
            info.AddValue("XmlDocument", xml);
        }
        else
        {
            info.AddValue("XmlDocument", (string)null);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, in the classes you want to serialize, replace your `XmlDocument` fields (and auto-implemented properties) with wrapper struct fields, e.g.:

```
[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    XmlDocumentSerializationWrapper doc;

    public XmlDocument Document { get { return doc; } set { doc = value; } }
}
```

The implicit operators in the struct handle automatic conversion from and to the wrapper.

Comment: Tanks a lot. it works correctly for XmlDocument , what about XslCompiledTransform ? how can i serialize this class?

Comment: @Hadi - I'm not as familiar with that class.  If you can figure out a way to extract the XML Stylesheet from the class as a string (or XmlDocument), you can use the same technique.  The preferred format for questions here is [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post), so I suggest asking a second question.